# How to create my own PropertyChangedEventArgs for INotifyPropertyChanged interface?

Tags: c#, .net, class, events, mvvm

I have come across an issue where i get in an endless loop between my `DataModel` and `ViewModel` with `PropertyChanged event`.

My structure:

```
public class SomeDataModel : DataModelBase
{
    public SomeDataModel()
    {

    }

    public object SomeProperty
    {
        get
        {
            //
        }
        set;
        {
            //
            OnPropertyChanged("SomeProperty");
        }
    }

    public bool SomeMethod()
    {
        SomeProperty = SomeNewObject
    }
}

public class SomeViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public SomeViewModel()
    {

    }

    public SomeDataModel SomeDataModel
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public object SomeProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return SomeDataModel.SomeProperty;
        }
        set
        {
            SomeDataModel.SomeProperty = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SomeProperty");
        }
    }
}
```

Both `ViewModel` and `DataModel` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Then i have a `listener` in my `ViewModelBase` for any `property` that changes in my `DataModel`:

```
private void DataModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    PropertyInfo toPropertyInfo = this.GetType().GetProperty(e.PropertyName);
    PropertyInfo fromPropertyInfo = DataModel.GetType().GetProperty(e.PropertyName);

    if (toPropertyInfo != null && fromPropertyInfo != null)
    {
        if (toPropertyInfo.CanWrite && fromPropertyInfo.CanRead)
        {
            toPropertyInfo.SetValue(this, fromPropertyInfo.GetValue(DataModel, null), null);
        }
    }
}
```

So now when the `property` gets set in the `DataModel`, the listener in `ViewModelBase` catches it and updates the relevant `property` in the `ViewModel`. But the set in the `ViewModel` sets it back to the `DataModel` with causes `OnPropertyChanged("SomeProperty");` to fire agian, ending in a endless loop.

1. Is there a quick work around to fix it? (**Note**: Can't change the structure)
2. Would i be able to create my own custom class, inheriting from `PropertyChangedEventArgs` and still have my `INotifyPropertyChanged` operations working?

I was thinking:

```
public class CustomPropertyChangedEventArgs : PropertyChangedEventArgs
{
    public CustomPropertyChangedEventArgs(string propertyName, SomeEnum enumName)
        : base(propertyName)
    {
        //Set enum
    }
}
```

and then in `OnPropertyChanged` i want to use the new `CustomPropertyChangedEventArgs` and pass the `enum` in that i want to use.

```
public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    CustomPropertyChangedEventArgs handler = this.PropertyChanged;

    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, new CustomPropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName, newEnum));
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll probably get blasted but I put have a class level list of all the property names currently being changed in each object (check and add on entering the method and remove on exiting the method). If, when I enter the OnPropertyChanged, the property name is already in the list I just return without doing anything. I would rather something not refresh than risk an endless loop.

Comment: Yes I would blast you in a code review.  :)

Comment: Amiram Korach has the best approach as long as you can be sure no one will call OnPropertyChanged but the Property Set code. Otherwise there will always be the risk of infinite loops. I'll take a bad review over irate users and crashing programs =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check if the value is the same and don't update it. This is how usually `INotifyPropertyChanged` is implemented. You fire the `OnPropertyChanged` only if it **really** changed.

```
public object SomeProperty
{
    get
    {
        return SomeDataModel.SomeProperty;
    }
    set
    {
        if (SomeDataModel.SomeProperty != value)
        {
            SomeDataModel.SomeProperty = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SomeProperty");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is perfect. Can't believe i missed this way. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
you can disable and enable the event to avoid loop
private void DataModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    OnPropertyChanged -= DataModel_PropertyChanged;
    PropertyInfo toPropertyInfo = this.GetType().GetProperty(e.PropertyName);
    PropertyInfo fromPropertyInfo = DataModel.GetType().GetProperty(e.PropertyName);

    if (toPropertyInfo != null && fromPropertyInfo != null)
    {
        if (toPropertyInfo.CanWrite && fromPropertyInfo.CanRead)
        {
            toPropertyInfo.SetValue(this, fromPropertyInfo.GetValue(DataModel, null), null);
        }
    }
    OnPropertyChanged += DataModel_PropertyChanged;
}
```

Comment: I would avoid this too.  There should be no reason for this if your models / view models are setup correctly.

Comment: It not thread safe as well, unless you really don't know what to do this is the last thing you can try.